# Suitable SVN for using LAMP

Tags: svn

I want to use SVN for one of my PHP projects. I'm using Windows XP SP2 which is the best one to use and install ?

Answer (score 0):

I siwtched to mac. But I liked using [Subeclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) for Eclipse and [Tortoise Subversion client](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: Tortoise supports SP3 and higher..i dnt know about Subeclipse..checking it out :)

Comment: Will i have to install Eclipse as well in order to use Subeclipse ?

Comment: Can you update to a newer SP or have you tried an older release of Tortoise SVN?

Comment: no haven't tried tortoise..to do that i have to change my system all over again :( ..i have a dual boot with Ubuntu as well as all the softwares in Windows..any other alternatives ?

Comment: Does any version of Tortoise support SP2 ?

Comment: @rajdeep-roy - just use TSVN 1.6 for any pre-sp3 Windows (local repo can be any version, BTW, even 1.7)

Comment: ok..checking it out..hope it will suffice my initial requirements

Comment: well it's your computer ;) - you maybe should update, because of varoius reasons. Here I found following link typing **sp2** in **search** (http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=2876313&dsForumId=4061)

Comment: guys..i'm downloading this as u mentioned http://www.filehorse.com/download-tortoisesvn/6809/ ..please check it out and tell if i m going to the right direction

Comment: @Rajdeep-roy - it's rather old 1.6 build. lastest was 1.6.16, better to find it on tortoisesvn.net site of author

Comment: @Lazy Badger: Thanks. I am trying it out now. Hope it will work on Win-7. Also i want to install it in my Hosting Server. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

SVN client - TortoiseSVN (maybe SmartSVN /portable?/ from Syntevo, if ShellExtension from TSVN doesn't have sense for you)

SVN server - VisualSVN Server

Comment: Hello Badger, Thanks for your response. Can you please guide me about how to install the Tortoise along with Visual SVN in the hosting server of my website, so that i can provide other people permissions to view and be a part of our team . I need this badly.

Comment: Tutorial how to install VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN: http://www.boedblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/tortoise-svn-and-svn-server-simple.html